# s3 bucket date path format for faster operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was told by one of the consultants from AWS itself that, while naming the folders(objects) in s3 with date. use MM-DD-YYYY for faster s3 operations like get Object, but i usually use YYYY-MM-DD. I don't understand what difference it makes, is there a difference, if yes, which one is better?

Answer (score 3):

This used to be a limitation due to the way data had been stored in the back end, but it doesn't apply (to the original extend, see jellycsc's comment below) anymore.

The reason for this recommendation was, that in the past Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) partitioned data using the key. With many files having the same prefix (like e.g. all starting with the same year) this could have led to reduced performance when many files needed to be loaded from the same partition.

However, since 2018, hashing and random prefixing the S3 key is no longer required to see improved performance: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

Comment: It still applies. The fact that they [increased the request rate](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/) makes it less necessary for people to care about the internal implementation details. I would still recommend people paying attention to the S3 object key naming style if it's used in production at large scale.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Frankly, unless you're a Netflix or a Pinterest, you are unlikely to be impacted by such rate limits. Most AWS users would never need to be concerned about enabling such high levels of performance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein As a developer who's doing daily operations on the production bucket of my company, I wish what you said was true and those implementation details can be 100% abstracted away, but unfortunately it's not. The truth is that lambda functions can easily overwhelm an S3 bucket if most of the objects that lambda is hitting are in the same S3 partition. This can result in occasional 503 slow down errors and S3 needs some time to create the partitions internally. The best way in this case is to create a support ticket and specify the partitions you want to be preallocated for you.

Answer (score 2):

S3 creates so-called *partitions* under the hood in order to serve up your requests to the bucket. Each partition has the ability to serve 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second. They partition the bucket based on the common prefix among all the object keys. MM-DD-YYYY date format would be slightly faster than YYYY-MM-DD because objects with MM-DD-YYYY naming will spread across more partitions.

Key take away here: more randomness **at the beginning of** the object keys will likely give you more performance out of the S3 bucket